How to call multiple middlewares from Nextjs middleware?
In my Next.js application, I have two middlewares :

query-params.ts : middelware for checking the query parameters in the url.
auth.ts: ClerkMiddleware

Both of these parameters are in middlewares folder.
I want to call both them from the middleware.ts file, but I could not know figured out the way to do it.
auth.ts

import { clerkMiddleware, createRouteMatcher } from "@clerk/nextjs/server"

const isPublicRoute = createRouteMatcher(["/", "/sign-in(.*)", "/sign-up(.*)", "/api(.*)"])

export const authMiddleware = clerkMiddleware(
  async (auth, req) => {
    if (!isPublicRoute(req)) {
      const { userId } = auth()

      if (!userId) {
        auth().redirectToSignIn({ returnBackUrl: req.url })
      }

      auth().protect()
    }
  },
  {
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
    publishableKey: process.env.DOCKER_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
    signInUrl: "/sign-in",
    signUpUrl: "/sign-up",
  }
)

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
}


query-params.ts
import { standardLoadProfilesOptions } from "@/features/solar-analytics/electricity-consumption/options"
import { powers } from "@/features/solar-analytics/shared/components/select-panel-power"
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"

// Middleware for handling query parameters
export const queryParamMiddleware = (request: NextRequest) => {
  const url = request.nextUrl
  const { searchParams } = url

  let shouldRedirect = false

  const defaultQueryParams = {
    tab: "map",
    slp: "H0",
    wp: "450",
    electricity: "5000",
  }

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(defaultQueryParams)) {
    const paramValue = searchParams.get(key)

    shouldRedirect = checkQueryParams(key, paramValue, searchParams, value) || shouldRedirect
  }

  if (shouldRedirect) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(url)
  }

  return NextResponse.next()
}

const checkQueryParams = (
  key: string,
  paramValue: string | null,
  searchParams: URLSearchParams,
  defaultValue: string
) => {
  switch (key) {
    case "tab":
      return checkTab(paramValue, searchParams, defaultValue)

    case "slp":
      return checkStandardLoadProfile(paramValue, searchParams, defaultValue)

    case "electricity":
      return checkElectricity(paramValue, searchParams, defaultValue)

    case "wp":
      return checkNominalPower(paramValue, searchParams, defaultValue)

    default:
      if (!searchParams.has(key)) {
        searchParams.set(key, defaultValue)
        return true
      }
      return false
  }
}

const checkTab = (paramValue: string | null, searchParams: URLSearchParams, defaultValue: string) => {
  if (!paramValue || (paramValue !== "custom" && paramValue !== "default" && paramValue !== "map")) {
    searchParams.set("tab", defaultValue)
    return true
  }
  return false
}

const checkStandardLoadProfile = (paramValue: string | null, searchParams: URLSearchParams, defaultValue: string) => {
  if (!paramValue || !standardLoadProfilesOptions.map(({ profile }) => profile).includes(paramValue)) {
    searchParams.set("slp", defaultValue)
    return true
  }
  return false
}

const checkElectricity = (paramValue: string | null, searchParams: URLSearchParams, defaultValue: string) => {
  if (!paramValue || isNaN(Number(paramValue))) {
    searchParams.set("electricity", defaultValue)
    return true
  }
  return false
}

const checkNominalPower = (paramValue: string | null, searchParams: URLSearchParams, defaultValue: string) => {
  if (!paramValue || !powers.map(({ value }) => value).includes(paramValue)) {
    searchParams.set("wp", defaultValue)
    return true
  }
  return false
}


middleware.ts
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

// how to call each middleware with its config matchers?!
}

